# Не могу зайти на cайт администратора

Tags: python, django

Я создал пользовательскую модель, и когда я создаю суперпользователя с помощью консоли, то мне пишет: "Superuser created successfully", но после этого я захожу на сайт администратора и не могу войти за теми данными, которые я ввел при создании пользователя.

Модель пользователя:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.utils import timezone


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault("is_staff", False)
        other_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", False)
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            **other_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            password=password,
            **other_fields
        )
        if other_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_staff=True.")
        if other_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser=True.")
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Username', db_index=True, max_length=16,
        help_text='Enter your username', unique=True
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='First name', max_length=20, help_text='Enter your name', null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Last name', max_length=20, help_text='Enter your surname')
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email', help_text='Enter your email', unique=True)
    sex = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Sex', max_length=6,
        choices=[('Female', 'Female'), ('Male', 'Male')], null=True
    )
    password = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Password', max_length=126,
        help_text='Enter your password'
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Staff', default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Superuser', default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

Настройки:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'catalog'
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['users.backends.Authentication']
```

backends.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import  ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import CustomUser


class Authentication(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        User = get_user_model()
        if email is None:
            email = kwargs.get(User.USERNAME_FIELD)
        if email is None or password is None:
            return
        try:
            user = User._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            User().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Cкрин из бд:

[image: бд]

Я пытался вставлять пароль прямо в бд, но мне это не помогло.

Comment: В поле `password` хранится не пароль, а хэш пароля, и 16 символов это определённо слишком мало для того, чтобы хэш смог поместиться. Сделайте его хотя бы 100 символов

Comment: Я пытался использовать пароль от класса AbstarctBaseUser на длину пароля 126, но мне это не помогло

Comment: Покажите скриншот базы с длиной 126, а дальше потом уже будем думать, почему ещё не помогло

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас сделаю

Comment: Уже поменял на значение 126, скрин изменил в вопросе.

Comment: `user.set_password` — это функция, а вы пытаетесь её заменить на какое-то значение, которое Django никак не будет использовать. Нужно вызвать функцию

Comment: Да, я исправил уже, но все равно не могу зайти

Comment: А password в базе хотя бы стал заполняться наконец?

Comment: Не уверен, имеет ли это отношение к проблеме, но теперь меня смущает, что `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`, хотя поле `username` в вашей модели тоже вполне существует

Comment: Да, сейчас покажу на скрине

Comment: Я менял  USERNAME_FIELD на username, но проблему оно не решило

Comment: А ещё меня смущает `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['users.backends.Authentication']`, может покажите код этого самого `users.backends.Authentication` тоже на всякий случай? (По крайней мере я в CustomUserManager бросающихся в глаза косяков больше не вижу)

Comment: Я понимаю, что использование класса AbstactUser было бы намного легче, но вдруг-когда нибудь нужно будет создавать пользователя с 0. Спасибо, что помогаете решить проблему!

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас покажу

Comment: `CustomUser.objects.get(email=email, password=password)` — а, ну вы пытаетесь искать пользователя по нехэшированному паролю, а надо функцию `check_password` для проверки хэша вызывать. Посмотрите, как выполняется [стандартная аутентификация с проверкой пароля](https://github.com/django/django/blob/282d58e19385ee4e5c125a9d3cba820949314f3f/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L40-L53), и повторите что-то подобное у себя

Comment: Хорошо,сейчас изменю модель аутентификации.

Comment: Я изменил, наверное, мне нужно переопределить get_by_natural_key

Comment: Ладно, мне нужно больше информации почитать про аутентификацию. Еще раз спасибо @andreymal

Answer (score 0):

У меня `password` и `email` в функци `authenticate` возращали `None` (я думал туда передаються данные ввода), мне пришлось брать данные полей ввода с помощью параметра `request`.

```
class Authentication(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if email is None or password is None:
            email = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=email)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            hash_paswword = user.password
            check = check_password(password, hash_paswword)
            if check and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
            print('Not correct password')
            return None
```

или

```
class Authentication(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request,email=None,password=None, **kwargs):
        User = get_user_model()
        if email is None or password is None:
            email = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
        try:
            user = User._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            User().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
            return user
```

Не знаю можно ли  по-другому сделать.